# How can I create a Code Module in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a code module with VBA. When I already have a code module I know that I can set it using:

```
Set cdmdl = wbk.VBProject.VBComponents(codeModuleName).CodeModule
```

But if the code module does not exist, how can I create it?

I've tried a few lines like:

```
Set cdmdl = new.wbk.VBProject.VBComponents(codeModuleName).CodeModule
Set cdmdl = create.wbk.VBProject.VBComponents(codeModuleName).CodeModule
```

But they haven't worked. I've also Googled, but this doesn't seem like a popular topic.

Comment: I want to update some Excel files. They already have their VBA code updated. But they don't have the buttons that activate said VBA scripts.

Comment: See this link http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Then shouldn't you want to just copy the buttons from the source worksheet to the destination?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
Public Function CreateModule(xlwb As Workbook) As VBComponent
    Dim module As VBComponent
    Set module = xlwb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    module.Name = "MyModule"
    module.CodeModule.AddFromString "public sub test()" & vbNewLine & _
                                    "    'dosomething" & vbNewLine & _
                                    "end sub"
    Set CreateModule = module
End Function
```

You can also `AddFromFile` if you have a .bas file you've exported and you want to load into a workbook.